# Execute complex script inside Azure ARM Template

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

Inside of one ARM , I have one "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts".  This is calling an custom powershell script.
When I am using the standard AZ methods everything works properly.
But when I want to use  AzureAD module (installing and importing ) the Script  fails during ARM deployment.

My question is how I can created a complex powershell script (calling other modules ) to use inside of one ARM?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what did you try? what is the error? have you tried `install-module azuread -scope currentuser`?

Comment: Could you please share the relevant parts of the script you're trying to run? It would also be helpful to get the actual error message you are getting- you can check this in the Azure Monitor logs.